# List manipulation: conditional result based on variable-length sublists

Tags: list-manipulation

Suppose I have the following lists:

```
eqexp={a,b,c,d}
eqval={e,f,g,h}
signval={{},{1},{-1},{1,-1}}
```

I want to create a new list of inequalities, where the signval list signals whether to use greater than or less than. I need it to handle empty sublists, and multi-component sublists. My desired output is:

```
{{},{b>f},{c<g},{d>h,d<h}}
```

All lists have the same number of top-level elements. eqexp and eqval are one-dimensional. signval is two-dimensional, but the length of the sub-lists is variable. The only numerical values allowed in signval are 1 and -1.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
MapThread[#3 /. {1 -> #1 > #2, -1 -> #1 < #2} &, {eqexp, eqval, signval}]
(*    {{}, {b > f}, {c < g}, {d > h, d < h}}    *)
```

Comment: Nice! I'm embarrassed that I didn't come up with that. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

```
MapThread[Through @ # @ ##2 &, {signval /. {1 -> Greater, -1 -> Less}, eqexp, eqval}]
```

> {{}, {b > f}, {c < g}, {d > h, d < h}}

Or do the replacement inside the first argument of `MapThread`:

```
 MapThread[Through @ ReplaceAll[ {1 -> Greater, -1 -> Less}][#] @ ##2 &, 
  {signval, eqexp, eqval}]
```

> same result

Alternatively, define a function `f0` with attribute `Listable` and use regular function application:

```
f0 = Function[, # @ ##2, Listable];
f0[signval /. {1 -> Greater, -1 -> Less}, eqexp, eqval]
```

> {{}, {b > f}, {c < g}, {d > h, d < h}}

Or use `ReplaceAll` in the definition of the listable function:

```
f1 = Function[, ReplaceAll[{1 -> Greater, -1 -> Less}][#] @ ##2, Listable];
f1[signval, eqexp, eqval]
```

> same result

Answer (score 1):

And the power of posting... I have found a way to do it:

```
MapThread[
  Function[{a, b, c}, If[c > 0, a > b, a < b], Listable], 
  {eqexp, eqval, signval}]
```

If there is a better way to do it, I would love to see it, though!