# List manipulation: conditional result based on variable-length sublists, part deux

Tags: list-manipulation

This is an outgrowth of [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/201123/list-manipulation-conditional-result-based-on-variable-length-sublists/201147#201147).

Suppose I have the following definitions:

```
eqexp = {a, b, c, d};
eqval = {e, f, g, h};
signval = {{}, {1}, {-1}, {1, -1}};
criteria = {{}, {i}, {j}, {k, l}};
```

As before, I want signval to determine whether the eqexp component is greater than or less than the eqval component. But now I have an extra list (criteria) which has the same structure as signval. I want the corresponding criteria value to be equal to zero as well, and then the resulting inequalities combined with an Or. So the desired output would be:

```
{False, b > f && i == 0, c < g && j == 0, 
 (d > h && k == 0) || (d < h && l == 0)}
```

The previous answers (without the criteria component) cleverly used a replacement rule on signval. I don't see how to do the same thing here. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Or @@@ MapThread[
  And @@@ Transpose[{#3 /. {1 -> #1 > #2, -1 -> #1 < #2}, Thread[#4 == 0]}] &,
    {eqexp, eqval, signval, criteria}]
```

On further thought, another `Thread` feels better than the `Transpose`:

```
Or @@@ MapThread[
  Thread[(#3 /. {1 -> #1 > #2, -1 -> #1 < #2}) && Thread[#4 == 0]] &,
  {eqexp, eqval, signval, criteria}]
```

Answer (score 3):

```
f0 = Function[, Construct @ ##, Listable];
Or @@@ f0[And, 
         f0[signval /. {1 -> Greater, -1 -> Less}, eqexp, eqval], 
         f0[EqualTo[0], criteria]]
```

> {False, b > f && i == 0, 
>    c < g && j == 0, (d > h && k == 0) || (d < h && l == 0)}

Comment: Why does your method not work if I define `f0 = Construct@## &; SetAttributes[f0, Listable];`? (Maybe this should be a full question by itself)

Comment: @Roman, great question; really puzzling.

Comment: I conclude that there are two ways of using attributes: (i) anonymous functions need the attributes assigned as the third argument of `Function` (*not* assigned to the variable holding the anonymous function, `f0` in your case), and (ii) regular functions (with patterns on the LHS) need the attributes assigned with `SetAttribute` to the function head. Mixing these two different ways of using attributes gives poor results.

Comment: Roman, that brings out an important difference between specifying a pure function `foo` as `foo = something&` versus `foo = Function[, something]`. The latter seems to be the only way to assign `Attributes` to `foo`.

Answer (score 1):

And once again, I post a question and right away figure out an answer. Here it is (although I would absolutely welcome more efficient ways to do it):

```
Or @@ MapThread[And, #] & /@ MapThread[{#3 /. {1 -> #1 > #2, -1 -> #1 < #2}, 
                    Map[# == 0 &, #4]} &, {eqexp, eqval, signval, criteria}]
```